# Spriter model not touching ground in?

Tags: sprites, html5, models, platformer, construct-2

I was attempting to make a game in Construct 2 by using my Spriter Models plugin. However, when I imported the model, rescaled it & changed a few things, I got this:

[image: My Spriter model isn't touching the platform.]

As seen in the picture, the Spriter model is not touching the platform ground.

Do you know of any ways I could have the model touch the ground?

Thanks in advance,

Jamie

Ps. Here is the link to the files, just in case you guys might wanna have a look at it:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B11opD9YgSqWbVhaNEVTcGhIRTA&usp=sharing

Pps. You will need the Spriter plugin for Construct 2 to open the project file. The Spriter model files will need Spriter to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your bounding box is **too large** for your sprite, try making sure that the sprite's feet touch the bottom of the bounding box in *Spriter*.

**EDIT:** It turns out can do it Contruct 2 itself, just double click on the part of the sprite that dosent touch the ground to open the sprite editor. 
Then click on crop and you're good to go!

[image: CROP]

Comment: Thanks, @ZEKE, but can you please tell me how to do it, eg tutorials stuffs, etc? (Sorry, I'm quite a noob at these programs at the moment.)

Comment: I had a look at the collision polygons on COnstruct 2 although it showed [this](http://imgur.com/g0toJE3). Not sure what is going on here, @ZEKE.

Comment: @Jamie The legs bounding box looks fine in the picture, is this the same for all body parts?

Comment: Yes. Could it be because of the rectangular bound-things? That when it was turned diagonal that it then shifts the shape diagonally? @ZEKE

Comment: If that's the case,@Jamie, then it might be better to create a regular sprite for collision and game logic(make it invisible), then attach the Spriter object. That way you won't have to bother with Spriter's weird collisions.